# Where is hibernation resume getting the device node from?

Tags: linux, grub2, hibernate

A while back, I set up hibernation on my Linux system. It's been working really well, up until tonight when I installed another hard disk, which shuffled the device node names around. So now on boot I get a message saying something to the effect of (I didn't write down the exact wording) `couldn't stat /dev/sda3` and asking me to enter the hibernation device node name or press Enter to continue without resuming from hibernation. This happens on a plain boot, not resuming from hibernation (I haven't tried resuming from hibernation, and am afraid it wouldn't work very well at all when the system can't properly identify the device to resume from hibernation from). When I do use hibernation, I do so using the /usr/sbin/hibernate script provided by the `hibernate` package (version `2.0+15+g88d54a8-1` is installed); I don't recall really setting it up in any particular manner.

This started because when I installed the new hard disk, it appeared earlier in the detection order than the SSD I have the root file system and swap space on. That shouldn't pose a problem, particularly as I am using stable /dev/disk/by-*/ names all around -- or so I thought.

I grepped through /boot and /etc, but none of the matches appear relevant.

/proc/swaps shows /dev/sdb3 which is the name that partition is now known under. /etc/fstab names it using its /dev/disk/by-id/ata-*-part3 name.

I'm using a fairly up-to-date Debian Wheezy. Here's my /etc/default/grub:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=300
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet pci=nomsi"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="uhci usb_keyboard"
```

and here is /boot/grub/grub.cfg:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
insmod uhci
insmod usb_keyboard
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

terminal_input console
terminal_output console
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=300
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
        set gfxpayload="${1}"
}
set linux_gfx_mode=
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-c050d662-f94a-447a-9342-0fc69f65a513' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod diskfilter
        insmod mdraid09
        insmod ext2
        set root='mduuid/0a1be8bb7679264ae488bd5c6f66e022'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='mduuid/0a1be8bb7679264ae488bd5c6f66e022'  c050d662-f94a-447a-9342-0fc69f65a513
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c050d662-f94a-447a-9342-0fc69f65a513
        fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=c050d662-f94a-447a-9342-0fc69f65a513 ro   quiet pci=nomsi
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-c050d662-f94a-447a-9342-0fc69f65a513' {
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.2.0-4-amd64-advanced-c050d662-f94a-447a-9342-0fc69f65a513' {
                load_video
                insmod gzio
                insmod part_msdos
                insmod diskfilter
                insmod mdraid09
                insmod ext2
                set root='mduuid/0a1be8bb7679264ae488bd5c6f66e022'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='mduuid/0a1be8bb7679264ae488bd5c6f66e022'  c050d662-f94a-447a-9342-0fc69f65a513
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c050d662-f94a-447a-9342-0fc69f65a513
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=c050d662-f94a-447a-9342-0fc69f65a513 ro   quiet pci=nomsi
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64
        }
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.2.0-4-amd64-recovery-c050d662-f94a-447a-9342-0fc69f65a513' {
                load_video
                insmod gzio
                insmod part_msdos
                insmod diskfilter
                insmod mdraid09
                insmod ext2
                set root='mduuid/0a1be8bb7679264ae488bd5c6f66e022'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='mduuid/0a1be8bb7679264ae488bd5c6f66e022'  c050d662-f94a-447a-9342-0fc69f65a513
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c050d662-f94a-447a-9342-0fc69f65a513
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=c050d662-f94a-447a-9342-0fc69f65a513 ro single
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64
        }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

and here is /etc/uswsusp.conf:

```
# /etc/uswsusp.conf(5) -- Configuration file for s2disk/s2both
resume device = /dev/sda3
splash = y
compress = y
early writeout = y
image size = 15529056419
RSA key file = /etc/uswsusp.key
shutdown method = platform
```

This should be an easy change if I can just find the proper place to make the change in. So, just **where is the resume code getting that device name from** and **how do I change it to reflect the new reality?**

*(I worked around the problem by swapping the devices involved such that the SSD came first in the detection order, but I'm still interested in an answer to this question.)*

Comment: What distribution are you using? What command do you use to hibernate and how did you set it up (if you did anything)? Post the content of `grub.cfg`.

Comment: @Gilles Done, see my edits.

Comment: Do you have a /etc/uswsusp.conf?

Comment: @etherfish As a matter of fact, I do. (Not sure why on Earth that didn't show up when I grepped through /etc.) See my edit. I imagine I know the answer by now but don't really have the time or ability to test right now, so am leaving things open for now for an answer based on what's now in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, your original `/etc/uswsusp.conf` was written by the scripts invoked by `dpkg` while installing `uswsusp`. To see the script, check `/var/lib/dpkg/info/uswsusp.config`.

To update it semi-automatically, use:

```
dpkg-reconfigure uswsusp
```

Or, edit it by hand and then use:

```
update-initramfs -u
```

I would sincerely encourage you to read `/usr/share/doc/uswsusp/README.Debian` as well.